# How to writer the condition A or B is zero , but not both is zero in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

What is the correct syntax for the following SQL statement ?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (A = 0 AND B != 0) OR (A!=0 AND B=0)
```

Thanks

Updated: How about negative case? I would like to check if A or B is non-zero , but not both is non-zero, Thanks

```
SELECT OperateProductId FROM DPS_UserLoginStatus Where OperateProductId <> 0 XOR OperateIssueId <> 0
```

Comment: get all case where a or b is zero , but not both are zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [XOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html) logical operator:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = 0 XOR B = 0
```

---

In terms of other operators, `a XOR b` (commonly `a ^ b` when used bitwise rather than logical), is equivalent to `(a and !b) or (b and !a)`. It's also equivalent to: `(a or b) and (!a or !b)`. In English, it's exactly what you're looking for: `a xor b` is true if and only if either `a` or `b` is true but both are not true.